# Download versões anteriores do navegador Edge

Tags: navegador-de-internet, microsoft-edge

Preciso testar minha aplicação web em versões antigas do navegador Edge da Micrsosoft. Estou usando maquina virtual para tal finalidade, no entanto, não estou conseguindo encontrar onde fazer download das versẽes mais antigas do nevegador. Versões como a 38, 40 e 41.

A versão que veio instalada é à 44.

PS. Preciso instalar localmente para poder debug e por isso sites que simulam ou permite acessar remotamente não atende minhas necessidades.

Alguem faz ideia de como realizer isso?

Comment: Cara qual é a sua intenção em testar em outras versões do Edge, só validar CSS?

Comment: Validar css e js. A solução Browser Stack foi a melhor solução e me ajudou 100% nessa tarefa. Recomendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez não seja a resposta perfeita, mas vou te dar umas dicas que podem te ajudar.

Primeiramente, fique atento na versão do Microsoft EdgeHTML e não na versão do aplicativo em si. Aperte `F12` no Edge que vc pode acessar a opção de renderizar sua página inclusive em versões do IE dentro do próprio Edge. E no menu superior `...` vai em configurações para ver a versão HTML do seu EDGE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Version number used for Edge is based on the number of EdgeHTML rather
>   than Edge itself. This is because EdgeHTML is the engine for Edge that
>   is related to feature support change.

Traduzindo: *O número da versão usado para Edge é baseado no número de EdgeHTML em vez do próprio Edge. Isso ocorre porque o EdgeHTML é o mecanismo do Edge que está relacionado à alteração de suporte de recursos.*

Fonte: https://caniuse.com/

Inclusive nesse site vc pode fazer várias validações de tag e classe que o EDGE aceita e em quais versões vai funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, vc sempre pode consultar o `Status de Desenvolvimento do EDGE` sabendo tudo que ele *Suporta*, coisas *Deprecadas*, em *Desenvolvimento*  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/mixblendmode/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dica:** Projeto do EDGE no GitHub, sim ele está no GitHub :D https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Status

Comment: Obrigado! A partir desses informações consegui criar uma caminho para realizar o debug...

Comment: Legal @LeandroMacedo que bom que deu certo ai! Viva a Microsoft! #sqn :)